# My heroku app has no dynos running - No web processes running means Application error when opening hosted website

Tags: php, html, heroku, web-hosting, host

I deployed my app on **Heroku** it doesn't work so when i checked out the app in **Heroku** website i've noticed that it has no dynos and it's supposed to be having one dyno by default if no Procfile detected.

That's what i've been doing the most of the time previously and it was working fine

Heroku logs says:

> No web processes running

it has no Procfile only some images css and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i was stuck in that for like 3 hours or more thank god it's fixed... fixed just by deleting the whole heroku app and then specifying the buildpack that you gonna use in your interactive terminal with this command line `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php` and you can add it on creating the app directly and that's what i did and it was fixed like that:

`heroku create myapp --buildpack heroku/php`

and the main reason was because of one python library was installed and i wasn't even using it so heroku finds two builpacks python and php and used the python one so when i did specifying that i'm actually using PHP everything works fine

i'd like to document it in public so others (including me) can find it later. Now, others can benefit from my misfortune LOL